# How to best make use of the same constants in both host and device code?

Tags: cuda, constants, idioms, gpu-constant-memory

Suppose I have some global constant data I use in host-side code:

```
const float my_array[20] = { 45.146, 54.633, 74.669, 12.734, 74.240, 100.524 };
```

(Note: I've kept them C-ish, no `constexpr` here.)

I now want to also use these in device-side code. I can't simply start using them: They are not directly accessible from the device, and trying to use them gives:

```
error: identifier "my_array" is undefined in device code
```

What is, or what are, the idiomatic way(s) to make such constants usable on both the host and the device?

Comment: How about a single non-const  `__managed__` array?

Comment: @AbatorAbetor: Is that in any sort of common use? If it is, write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This approach was suggested by Mark Harris in [an answer in 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9477152/1593077):

```
#define MY_ARRAY_VALUES 45.146, 54.633, 74.669, 12.734, 74.240, 100.524
__constant__ float device_side_my_array[2] = { MY_ARRAY_VALUES };
const        float host_side_my_array[2]   = { MY_ARRAY_VALUES };
#undef MY_ARRAY_VALUES

__device__ __host__ float my_array(size_t i) {
#ifdef __CUDA_ARCH__
    return device_side_my_array[i];
#else
    return host_side_my_array[i];
#endif
}
```

But this has some drawbacks:

- Not actually using the same constants, just constants with the same value.
- Duplication of data.
- Takes up constant memory, which is a rather limited resource.
- Seems a bit verbose (although maybe other options are even more so).

I wonder if this is what most people use in practice.

Note:

- In C++ one might use the same name, but in different sub-namespaces within the `detail::` namespace.
- Doesn't use `cudaMemcpyToSymbol()`.

Comment: You will always have duplication of data (CPU + GPU memory), if you do not want to send the data over the PCIe bus with each access from the side they do not reside on. Constant memory is very usable, if all threads of a warp access the same data, if the overall size is limited (relevant is maximum size of constants and constant cache). As alternative you can store the constants in global memory or shared memory or in the registers of each thread.